# Imperial units - mass and force

Tags: units

I was rudely informed on an answer here that 1 lb is a force and I 'didn't understand' mass.

(I am not interested in relative merits of systems of units - only dimensions..)

Now - we know that Force has dimensions [mass]$\cdot$[length]$\cdot$[time]$^{-2}$

So my question is

When the imperial users refer to a force of '1 lb' do they mean

The Weight of 1 lb mass i.e. 32 lb ft $s^{-2}$
or
1lb with an acceleration of 1 ft $s^{-2}$

Although I was brought up (UK 60s) with imperial units the above forces were clearly identified as
1 pound force (lbf) & 1 Poundal

Has the US dropped these definitions, and if so what do they mean by a 'force' of 1 lb

Comment: I am so glad using SI units while growing ups in 70s/80s......

Comment: All my advanced study and professional engineering and was done in SI (thank goodness) but we did use imperial when younger.

Answer (score 1):

When the pound (lb) was first defined in the 14th century, the distinction between weight and mass was not understood. So "pound" can refer to either a unit of mass or a unit of weight i.e. force. If the interpretation is not clear from context, then the terms [pound-mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)) (abbreviation lb$_m$) and [pound-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force)) (abbreviation ib$_f$) can be used to distinguish between the two meanings.

The [poundal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poundal) is also a unit of force - it is the force required to accelerate 1 pound-mass at an acceleration of 1 foot per second per second. It is therefore equal to approximately $\frac 1 {32}$ pound-force.

Comment: As noted in my question - I understand both those units, and the distinction.

IF a US user says ' a force of 1 lb' - WHICH do they mean Poundal, or Pound Force?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it was _weight_, not _force_, they didn't know how to distinguish from mass. I'm sure everyone in the 1300s knew you can push a mass with varying amounts of force, or "oomph", or whatever they'd call it.